What is the space of closed curves (regardless of scale)?
Consider the set of closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ trough the origin and do the quotient by the following:

Two curves are equivalent if one can be reparametrized into the other
Two curves are equivalent if (the appropiate reparametrized versions) one is a scaled version of the other

I'm wondering if something is known about this space. What is its cardinality? Is there a standard topology? Does anything change if we only consider $\mathcal{C}^k$ curves for some $k\le\infty$? What if the regions enclosed by the curves are required to be convex?
I ask for the convex-differentiable case because I think it's really no different from the space of functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0 (up to scale) and that space must be well understood.
Thanks in advance
